# sum all rows and headers if row and header dates are less than or equal to a particular date

Tags: excel-formula

I have a table with dates as headers for both row and column - each cells sums transactions with the origination date in the row and clearing date in the column.

e.g.

```
               31/1/2019    28/2/2019    31/3/2019
31/1/2019           -100         -200         -300
28/2/2019            -10          -20          -30
31/3/2019             -1           -2           -3
```

I would like a formula to sum the matrix where the column headers and row headers are less or equal to a particular date.

Using the example above:

```
31/1/2019 = -100
28/2/2019 = -330
31/3/2019 = -666
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying for a while to do what you ask with formulas and I couldn't so I wrote a little function that will work for you as a formula. You need to put this code:

```
Option Explicit
Function MySumIf(SumRange As Range, Criteria As Range) As Double

    Dim arr, i As Long, j As Integer

    arr = SumRange.Value
    For i = 2 To UBound(arr)
        For j = 2 To UBound(arr, 2)
            If arr(i, 1) <= Criteria.Value And arr(1, j) <= Criteria.Value Then MySumIf = MySumIf + arr(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

End Function
```

On a module inside VBA. How can you do that? Press `ALT+F11` on your excel and a window will pop with VBA -> To the left you will se a window called Projects, there you press right click with your mouse on anything and go to insert -> module -> paste the code on the blank window it will appear.

To use the function just write `=MySumIf(RangeToSumWithDates,DateCriteria)` Like this:

[image: Formula]

The result is:

[image: Result]

Hope it helps. Only downside is that you need to share this code in order to work for someone else, or share the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a formula like this:

```
=IF(AND($A$2<=$A6,$B$1<=$A6),SUM($B$2:INDEX($B$2:$D$4,MATCH($A6,$A$2:$A$4,1),MATCH($A6,$B$1:$D$1,1))),0)
```

[image]

Or slightly revised:

```
=IFERROR(SUM($B$2:INDEX($B$2:$D$4,MATCH($A6,$A$2:$A$4,1),MATCH($A6,$B$1:$D$1,1))),0)
```